# Unable to restart production rails server when started as daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am running a rails server on an Ubuntu EC2 instance and have run into an issue when it comes to deploying (and restarting) my server. The odd thing is; everything seems to work fine when I start a vanilla server (`rails server`), but when I start the server as a daemon it does not reset (`rails server -d`).

I use Capistrano to do deployment. As far as I can tell there is no issue; it pulls down my latest branch, runs migrations and does a `touch tmp/restart.txt`. I had tried making my `tmp/restart.txt` a shared file, but that does not seem to be the issue (although it is a configuration I think I'll keep). After discovering Capistrano is likely working as expected I tried sshing into the server and running `touch tmp/restart.txt` myself. It works for the vanilla server but not the daemon.

Has anyone seen this issue before? If there is more info I could provide please let me know!

**Env:**

`ruby 2.6.3p62` @/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby

`Rails 5.2.3` @/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rails

`Bundler version 2.1.2` @/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/bundle

`Node v13.8.0` @/home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.8.0/bin/node

My logs, tmp, and config/master.key are shared as part of my Capistrano setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using puma or unicorn or passenger? apache or nginx? restarting the process depends more on that than anything.

personally, I like using Passenger with apache and when I restart apache, the passenger process restarts automatically.

Comment: I did not think to mention that, thanks! I am using Puma (which I believe is shipped with rails). When I run `$ puma -v` it seems I'm using version 3.12.1. I'll dig more into this.

I'm not using anything more advanced then puma; apache, nginx, ect.

Comment: what is starting puma ? I don't know if puma has the ability to refresh.. it just runs the app. usually there are some sort of watchdog, you can kill puma process and it will get respawn by its parent/observer.

Comment: Ah, you'r right. I think I was expecting my production environment to be have the same as development where I have spring running. I'll look into some of the services you mentioned.

Would it be bad to just manually restart my server via capistrano by killing it and starting again?

Comment: @IshmaelKing are you running executing `rails server` on your server in production? that is quite unconventional. you can kill and restart, but there will be a short downtime. I recommend you setup Apache or Nginx depending on your preferences. and have Passenger module install to automatically manage your rails app.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I am very new to all of this so when I first got my AWS instance up it was nice to see my server running remotely by using `rails sever`. I have since moved to passenger/nginx when it comes to running/restarting my server.

Thanks a ton!